# MySql Simple Query Performance - 1m rows

Tags: mysql

I'm currently the developer behind the site [Twitch Links](https://www.twitchlinks.com) (NSFW). I'm the sole creator and I'm starting to feel concerned about a simple query that is the back bone of the web site (I'm by no means a DBA).

To quickly summarize, it's collecting URL's from Twitch.TV chat. It's grabbed around 700k in 3 weeks. The site visually displays the most recent Imgur's and Youtube videos. I have a single "links" table, with a "favourites" table where I stored user favourited links (Id, LinkId, UserId).

Here's the query:

```
SELECT
    Id,
    URL,
    CapturedOn,
    Channel,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM favourites WHERE LinkId = links.Id) AS NumFavourites, # Is this bad per row?
    Type,
    Data,
    CapturedBy
FROM links
WHERE
    Channel LIKE "%%" AND       # Can sometimes be populated with a single value, e.g. "Channel like '%riotgames%'"
    Type IN ('Imgur', 'YouTube') AND    # Can sometimes be "Type LIKE '%Imgur%'" or "Type LIKE '%Facebook%'" - there are about 20 different types.
    Deleted = 0 AND             # Out of 500k rows, about 100 will be deleted.
    Id > 0 AND         # Will be set to a high ID after first view to only return latest rows.
    Data IS NOT NULL            # Exclude badly parsed links.
ORDER BY
    Id DESC LIMIT 40;
```

Here's the explain plan:

[image: Explain Plan]

Here are the keys:

```
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `idx_links_Channel` (`Channel`),
  KEY `idx_links_Type` (`Type`),
  KEY `idx_links_CapturedOn` (`CapturedOn`)
```

The "Channel LIKE" statement can change when requesting links for a particular users favourite channels only. This becomes:

```
Channel IN (SELECT CONCAT('#', ChannelName) FROM channelfavourites WHERE UserId = X) AND
```

There is an index on the "favourites" table on its Id, UserId, LinkId columns.

There is an index on "channelfavourites" for column "UserId".

Here are my questions about it:

1. Why is it showing that 382k rows are being scanned? Shouldn't the order by ID DESC LIMIT 40 always limit it to much less, ie, find 40 rows matching the WHERE then stop?
2. When the sites been running a year, and it has say 12m rows, will this query still scale? Will MySQL be clever enough to realize with the "ORDER BY Id DESC" to start at the end of the data set on disk and work backwards?

I've been thinking to flatten this query completely to a more view style table "`SELECT l.* FROM validlinks v JOIN links l ON l.Id = v.LinkId ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 40`". But will that simple join be worth it?

Any input would be appreciated.

## Info

VERSION(): 5.7.10-log

Indexes: [image: Indexes]

Create SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `links` (
   `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `Type` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
   `URL` text,
   `CapturedOn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   `CapturedBy` text,
   `Channel` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
   `Data` text,
   `Deleted` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
   `DonationId` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
   KEY `idx_links_Channel` (`Channel`),
   KEY `idx_links_Type` (`Type`),
   KEY `idx_links_CapturedOn` (`CapturedOn`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=756661 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: `LIKE` is murder on databases. Consider a full-text index.

Comment: Thanks, not considered those. If I can eliminate the "LIKE" to just be a "Channel = 'Blah'", would that be even better?

Comment: please post the outputs from: SELECT VERSION(); SHOW INDEX FROM links; SHOW CREATE TABLE links; - i am nearly sure that you must create a composite index. MySQL use "normaly" only one index per query

Comment: Exact matches can be indexed, they're often very fast. `LIKE` and `RLIKE` cannot, MySQL has to test against each row that *could* match.

Comment: @BerndBuffen Done.

Comment: @MeshMan - thanks - try the **CREATE INDEX from  tadman and post a new EXPLAIN. if the result not good for you post the ouput from the last SQL; SET PROFILING=ON ; SHOW PROFILE ALL; - after this you can stop profiling with SET PROFILING=OFF

Comment: @MeshMan - it is also possible that you can optimize your my.cnf to speedup the query or to set some optimzer switches

Comment: @BerndBuffen Here's the new explain plan after the new index: http://i.imgur.com/aAPjixo.png

Comment: @MeshMan - sh.... - you can see that the optimizer do not use the new index ;-( , but do not tell them to do this. thats not a good idea. i will thing a little bit. and will send you a query (with sub query) and changes datatypes to speedup your request. you can only send me the output from add this to your query and execute it : SELECT ........ PROCEDURE ANALYSE();

Comment: @BerndBuffen Thanks for that, never seen that ANALYSE() function before now. I'm concerned over the amount of "rows" being reported in the explain plan. Even a simple SELECT * FROM links, if I use a WHERE clauses even on the ID primary key, it shows "rows" as 300k+ in the explain plan. I don't understand why it says it needs to scan that many rows when I use LIMIT 40...

Comment: @MeshMan - you use ORDER BY in your query, so i can be that the last row is the first after the order and after this MySQL can do the LIMIT on the hole Resuleset

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112607/discussion-between-meshman-and-bernd-buffen).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want speed you're going to have to jettison a bunch of junk in this query.

Don't flag things as deleted, delete them. If you need to archive those, dump them in a secondary table. Just get them out of the way.

Clear out invalid data as aggressively as you can. This eliminates tests like `NOT NULL` in your query. You can filter any stray records you get in your application layer.

Don't use `LIKE`, it results in huge table scans. Instead use a full-text index. Those are significantly faster.

Build an index that incorporates all of your conditions. Try and order it such that the first items exclude the most data relative to the later ones.

If you had to index this as-is:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_links_for_searching (Deleted, Type, id)
```

Add in full-text and you're doing even better.

Comment: Ouch, now Im embarrassed. I thought adding the indexes by column was the right way to do it. Thanks Tadman.

Comment: @MeshMan No trouble at all. This is something you've got to experiment a lot with to understand, so keep at it. Benchmarking a database loaded down at scale is very informative.